# IndexError: list index out of range for a csv with no headers

Tags: python-3.x, csv

My data looks like the snapshot attached (csv with no headers, and values of "`person` `long` `lat`" are separated by space.
I am trying to parse this in python 3.6 into a dictionary of users with their xy coorinates. The code below gives
"IndexError: list index out of range"
[my dataset screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nz2YN.png)
What am I doing wrong?

```
inFile = io.open('myfile.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
reader = csv.reader(inFile, dialect='excel')

user_list_geo = {}

for row in reader:
    user_list_geo.setdefault(row[0], []).append([float(row[1]),float(row[2])])
```

Comment: are you sure you don't have empty rows?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have empty rows in your csv, you could simply check if row exists.

```
for row in reader:
    if row:
        user_list_geo.setdefault(row[0], []).append([float(row[1]),float(row[2])])
```

You can read about `lineTerminator` which can help you to skip empty rows in [here](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.lineterminator)